# How to use mongoose Promise - mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, promise

Can someone give me an example on how to use a Promise with mongoose. Here is what I have, but its not working as expected:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.local('myStuff', myLib.process(req.path, something));
  console.log(res.local('myStuff'));
  next();
});
```

and then in myLib, I would have something like this:

```
exports.process = function ( r, callback ) {
  var promise = new mongoose.Promise;
  if(callback) promise.addBack(callback);

  Content.find( {route : r }, function (err, docs) {
     promise.resolve.bind(promise)(err, docs);

  });

  return promise;

};
```

At some point I am expecting my data to be present, but how can I access it, or get at it?

Comment: Relevant read - http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

Answer (score 48):

In the current version of Mongoose, the `exec()` method returns a Promise, so you can do the following:

```
exports.process = function(r) {
    return Content.find({route: r}).exec();
}
```

Then, when you would like to get the data, you should make it async:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
     res.local('myStuff', myLib.process(req.path));
     res.local('myStuff')
         .then(function(doc) {  // <- this is the Promise interface.
             console.log(doc);
             next();
         }, function(err) {
             // handle error here.
         });
});
```

For more information about promises, there's a wonderful article that I recently read:
http://spion.github.io/posts/why-i-am-switching-to-promises.html

Comment: The newest version of mongoose also lets you use the result of `find()` as a promise, without needing to call `exec`. So you could just do: `Content.find({route: r}).then(function(content) { } );`

Comment: why do you use res.local? can you directly use `var a = myLib.process(req.path)`

Comment: @OMGPOP I think OP wanted to use promise in templates. Yes, you can use it directly.

Answer (score 30):

Mongoose already uses promises, when you call `exec()` on a query.

```
var promise = Content.find( {route : r }).exec();
```

Comment: As of Mongoose 4.13, `find()` already returns a promise. No need to call `exec()`.

Answer (score 23):

[Mongoose 4.0 Release Notes](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/wiki/4.0-Release-Notes)

> Mongoose 4.0 brings some exciting new functionality: schema validation
>   in the browser, query middleware, validation on update, **and promises
>   for async operations**.

With *mongoose@4.1* you can use any promises that you want

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
```

Another example with polyfilling global.Promise

```
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

So, you can just do later

```
Content
  .find({route : r})
  .then(function(docs) {}, function(err) {});
```

Or

```
Content
  .find({route : r})
  .then(function(docs) {})
  .catch(function(err) {});
```

P.S. [Mongoose 5.0](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/wiki/5.0-Deprecation-Warnings)

> Mongoose 5.0 will **use native promises by default** if available,
>   otherwise no promises. You will still be able to set a custom promises
>   library using `mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');`, however,
>   mpromise will not be supported.

Comment: could you give an example of native promise use with mongoose 5.0 ?

Comment: Mongoose 5.0 not released yet

Comment: i have imported like `import { Mongoose } from "mongoose";` in this case how can i use bluebird and promise?

Answer (score 5):

I believe you're looking for

```
exports.process = function ( r, callback ) {
  var promise = new mongoose.Promise;
  if(callback) promise.addBack(callback);

  Content.find( {route : r }, function (err, docs) {
     if(err) {
       promise.error(err);
       return;
     }
     promise.complete(docs);

  });

  return promise;

};
```

Answer (score 0):

On this page:http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

> The title is **Plugging in your own Promises Library**

Answer (score -1):

Use the bluebird Promise library like this:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongoose = Promise.promisifyAll(mongoose);

User.findAsync({}).then(function(users){
  console.log(users)
})
```

This is thenable, such as:

```
User.findAsync({}).then(function(users){
      console.log(users)
    }).then(function(){
      // more async stuff
    })
```

Comment: This answer is outdated. Mongoose already has native promise support support, so there is no need to Promisify the methods.

Comment: This would be for versions prior to 4.0