# Sometimes data isn't being displayed in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

When i click `ctr + r` sometimes the whole data doesn't show up. on my `("/")` page I have a left side and a right side. The left side should display all of the data and the right side should display a random piece of data. It works most of the time but if I click `ctr + r` on the keyboard to refresh sometimes some or all the data doesn't appear .

This is how my code works.

- sets the `comps` collections to the data from `arr` (now I have 3 elems. 3 docs).
- Actually before it does that it deletes all the content from the collection so every time I go to "/" I get only 3 docs (for testing)
- find all docs with the filters and display them on the left side (I can display them because the find method returns doc) then I use doc in the render.
- use the findOne() to get the random.

Also you should note that I do have the console.log() in my code and that consoles the correct information. I get all 3 documents in the console.

To be honest I never used more than one method on the model when rendering and I never used a random method in a model method. so I maybe messing that up.

I want to know why sometimes the data doesn't appear when I refresh.

server.js

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    ejs    = require("ejs");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/comp1");
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;   
app.set("view engine", "ejs"); 
app.use(express.static("./public"));

var Comp = require("./models/company.js");

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    var arr = [
    {name : "comp1",industry : "industry1", ranking: 20},
    {name : "comp2",industry : "industry2", ranking: 5},
    {name : "comp3",industry : "industry3", ranking: 10}
    ]
 Comp.count({}, function(err, count){
       var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
        Comp.find({}).remove({}, function(){
            console.log("removed")
        })
        Comp.create(arr, function(err, docs){
            console.log(docs)
            console.log(count)
        })

       Comp.find({}, 'name -_id ranking', {sort :{ranking :1}}, function(err, doc){
            if(err) throw err;
            Comp.findOne().skip(random).exec(function(err, result){
                res.render("index",{data : doc , count: random , result : result})
            })

        })
   })

})




app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("node is listening on port : " + port );
})
```

index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    ontop
    <div class="container clearfix">
        <div class="leftSide">TEST
            <%= data%>
            <%data.forEach(function(comp){%>
                <div><%= comp.name %> <span>ranking : <%= comp.ranking %></span></div>
            <%  }); %>
        </div>
        <div class="rightSide">side <%= count %>
            <div><%=result %></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

company.ejs

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var compSchema = new Schema({
    name : String,
    industry: String,
    ranking : Number,
    created_at : Date,
    updated_at : Date,
    inc : Number

});

compSchema.pre("save", function(next){
    var currentDate = new Date();
    this.updated_at = currentDate;
    var counter = 0;
    this.inc = counter;
    counter++;

    if(!this.created_at){
        this.created_at = currentDate;
    }
    next();
})

var Comp = mongoose.model("Comp", compSchema);

module.exports = Comp;
```

Comment: You are using asynchronous code synchronously. This will never work the way you expect it. Just find some examples how to do multiple DB queries and I think you find your answer

Comment: would promises help me here? this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise? I didn't want to have to learn this.

Comment: The methods like `findOne` are synchronous?  and I'm using that in a callback which is messing me up so I should use something like .then() is that what is messing up?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest but **NOT RECOMMENDED** way to do what you want would be the code bellow but it usually leads to **callback hell** or **Pyramid of doom** and its hard to read so **don't use this**!!!!

```
Comp.count({}, function(err, count){
   Comp.find({}).remove({}, function(){
      Comp.create(arr, function(err, docs){
         Comp.find({}, ..., function(err, doc){                
            Comp.findOne().skip(random).exec(function(err, result){
                res.render("index",{})
            })    
         }) 
      })
   })    
})
```

another way could be to use **async.js**

```
async.series([
    function(callback){
        Comp.count({}, function(err, count){
            callback(null, count);
        });
    },
    function(callback){
        Comp.find({}).remove({}, function(){
            callback(null);
        });
    },
    function(callback){
        Comp.create(arr, function(err, docs){
            callback(null);
        });
    },
    function(callback){
        Comp.find({}, ..., function(err, doc){ 
            callback(null);
        });
    },
    function(callback){
        Comp.findOne().skip(random).exec(function(err, lastResult){
            callback(null, lastResult);
        });
    }
],
// optional callback, results is an array of results from each callback if any
function(err, results){
    // results is now equal to [count, lastResult]
    res.render("index",{})
});
```

and finally Promises *I haven't tried or used this, so not 100% sure* but something like this

```
var promise = Comp.count({}).exec();

promise.then(function(count) {
    return Comp.find({}).remove({}).exec();
})
.then(function() {
    return Comp.create(arr, ).remove({}).exec();
})
.then(function() {
    return Comp.find({}).remove({}).exec();
})
.then(function() {
    return Comp.find({}).skip(random).exec();
})
.then(function(result) {
    res.render("index",{})
})
```

Have a look here for some more details about promises on mongoose [How to use mongoose Promise - mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022099/how-to-use-mongoose-promise-mongo)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wrote a question about `return Model.create(arr).exec()`. that doesn't work. maybe you have some input on this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37309637/return-model-createarr-exec-is-not-working-in-mongoose

Comment: I don't think that was the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37313905/when-i-refresh-the-page-sometimes-the-sorted-data-is-not-available