# return Model.create(arr).exec() is not working in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I heard that exec "returns a promise" so I'm using exec it do asynchronous calls. This question is inspired my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37307007/sometimes-data-isnt-being-displayed-in-browser). The commentator  said my code is not working because :

> You are using asynchronous code synchronously

I was trying to fix that by using the below code. Don't know if this code will make it not sync but I heard that promises help with that.

so I have this and I cannot create(save) the data but I can delete it. why cant I use the same pattern for `create` as i did for `remove`?

```
var Comp = require("./models/company.js");
  var arr = [
    {name : "comp1",industry : "industry1", ranking: 20},
    {name : "comp2",industry : "industry2", ranking: 5},
    {name : "comp3",industry : "industry3", ranking: 10}
  ]


Comp.find({}).exec()
    .then(function(docs){
        return Comp.remove({}).exec()
        .then(function(){
            console.log("deleted")
        })
    })
    .then(function(){
        return Comp.create(arr).exec()
        .then(function(data){
            console.log(data)
        })
    })
```

and can you help get to my original goal which was in my other question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `then` funtion does not return promise, the **exec does**!

So you need to do `return Comp.remove({}).exec()`

```
Comp.find({}).exec()
.then(function(docs){
    return Comp.remove({}).exec();
})
.then(function(result_of_remove){
    return Comp.create(arr).exec();
})
.then(function(result_of_create){
    ....
})
```

Comment: Important information. `.create` returns a promise so you shouldn't use `.exec()`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358133/trouble-using-promises-with-mongoose .. That's why I got the error.

Answer (score 2):

first of all you should confirm you `mongoose` version.

in older version:

`Model.create(doc)`  returns a query object; call the `exec` method of the query will trigger the database operation and return a promise.

in new version (i am using `4.4.8`) of `mongoose` `Model.create(doc)`  and 'Model.remove(con)' returns a promise directly.

so check with your version to see if you  need to remove some `exec`

last but not least add `catch` call to check if you got some errors, it helps when debug

```
Comp.find({}).exec()
.then(function(docs){
    return Comp.remove({}).exec();
})
.then(function(result_of_remove){
    return Comp.create(arr).exec();
})
.then(function(result_of_create){
    ....
})
.catch(function(error){
  console.log(error)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about the versions

Comment: Yup, that was my issue: the .exec() on my create() method was not working.  Removed the .exec() and now it returned properly.  thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I normally use .exec() when I want to return a Promise when working with

Model.findOne(...).exec()

#### Model.create(...) returns a Promise.

> The .exec() function does not exist for Model.create(...)