# trouble using promises with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

Can someone tell me why this promise setup doesn't work. It supposed to remove the docs then add it then find it then console it. It's not consoling the data.

```
  var Comp = require("./models/company.js");
  var arr = [
    {name : "comp1",industry : "industry1", ranking: 20},
    {name : "comp2",industry : "industry2", ranking: 5},
    {name : "comp3",industry : "industry3", ranking: 10}
  ]

  var output = {};  
  var promise =  Comp.find({}).exec()
  promise.then(function(res){
        console.log("removed")
        return Comp.remove({}).exec()
    })
    .then(function(){
        return Comp.create(arr).exec()
    })

    .then(function(data){
         return Comp.find({}).exec();
    })
    .then(function(data){
        console.log(data)
    })
```

EDIT : :

caught an error

`[TypeError: Comp.create(...).exec is not a function]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Model.create`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create) returns a promise, so there's no need to call `.exec()` on the return value.

```
.then(function(){
    return Comp.create(arr);
})
```

Comment: oh cool. So queries don't return a promise but if you use `exec` it does. but `create` and `save` returns a promise so you shouldn't use `exec` . Right?

Comment: @jackblank That's right. When in doubt, check the [API docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html) for Mongoose.