# "mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated" error when testing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js

For a while I have been getting this error and I decided to fix it today but after an hour trying to fix it I can find the solution.

When I test my mongoose User model this error/warning is generated:

```
Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
```

Here is my test:

```
  1 var assert = require('chai').assert;
  2 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
  3 var clearDB = require('mocha-mongoose')(require('../../config/database').uri, { skip: ['workouts'] });
  4 var database = require('../../config/database').connect;
  5
  6 var User = require('../../app/models/user');
  7 var user = new User({});
  8
  9 var req_body = {
 10   username: "garyvee",
 11   email: "gary@vaynermedia.com",
 12   password: "secret"
 13 };
 14
 15 describe('User', function() {
 16   beforeEach(function(done) {
 17     user.username = "johnsmith";
 18     user.email = "john@gmail.com";
 19     user.password = "secret";
 20     done();
 21   });
 22
 23   it('can be saved', function() {
 24     return user.save(function(err: any) {
 25       assert.isNull(err);
 26     })
 27   });
 28 });
```

I think it has something to do with the `.save` but I don't know how to fix it. Can someone help me and tell me how to fix it so that error/warning isn't shown.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to plugin a promise library (q, bluebird, the es6 one...)

```
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
```

Comment: Thanks man, Your solutions works :)

Comment: I still get this warning when using the above with node 6.9.1, mongoose 4.8.3 and bluebird 3.4.7.

Comment: Jackpile, you also have to add it to the models.js too

Answer (score 14):

From node 4.x you can just use ES6 promises:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = Promise;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example that may help. 
Using es6 modules (instead of CommonJS require) this works for me:

```
// mongoose's Promise library is deprecated, using es6's: 
import es6Promise from 'es6-promise';
mongoose.Promise = es6Promise.Promise;
```

Comment: See also this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38153706/2650732

Answer (score 1):

you can refer to
[How to use mongoose Promise - mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022099/how-to-use-mongoose-promise-mongo/41605022#41605022)

**the page content :**

> On this page:http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
>
> The title is Plugging in your own Promises Library