# "mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated" in Typescript Application

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angular

How to resolve "mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated" from a Typescript Application.

I'm getting the following error:

**Left-hand side of assignment expression cannot be a constant or a read-only property.**

I am using a [MEAN stack with Angular 2](https://github.com/ericmdantas/generator-ng-fullstack) and would like to have mongoose use the bluebird promises library.

I am getting an error when I attempt to follow these instructions on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39333229/mpromise-mongooses-default-promise-library-is-deprecated-error-when-testing) and [Mongo](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html)

To be honest, I'm unsure if my issue is just lack of knowledge of Typescript or if I am doing something else wrong.

```
"use strict";

import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
var dbConst = require('../constants/db.json');
var bluebird = require("bluebird");

export class DBConfig {
    static init():void {
      const URL = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') ? process.env.MONGOHQ_URL
                                                          : dbConst.localhost;

      mongoose.Promise = bluebird;     // <-- THIS IS WHERE ERROR OCCURS
      mongoose.connect(URL);
      mongoose.connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'An error ocurred with the DB connection: '));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following should work:

```
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";
import * as bluebird from "bluebird";

//either this
(<any>mongoose).Promise = bluebird;

//OR pass it in as an option
const connection = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://localhost:27017", { 
    promiseLibrary: bluebird
});
```