# Trying to call the method in UserSchema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to call the `makePassword` method into the `UserSchema.pre('save')`. but get this error

```
(node:8252) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
```

I've also tries with including the `mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;` before `mongoose.connect(config.database);`, Please suggest

Comment: Which version of Node and Mongoose are you using ?

Comment: Follow this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39333229/mpromise-mongooses-default-promise-library-is-deprecated-error-when-testing

Answer (score 0):

this generally happens when a library is missing out..like Bluebird, Q...so try including it in .
mongoose.Promise = require('Q');