# Node js array value accessing issue

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have array and i want to store the query result in array below is the code

```
var button_settings=[];
con.query("SELECT * from ht_button", function (err, result, fields){
   if (err) throw err;
   button_settings.push(result);
});
console.log(button_settings);
```

it shows [] i want the stored result.

Comment: What's the issue here?

Comment: i am not able to get the stored values

Comment: You need a promise here. console.log fired before the function callback

Comment: can you give any code sample please , thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022099/how-to-use-mongoose-promise-mongo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to solve this issue is to write `console.log` inside the callback. That's what is highly recommended.

Now coming to the part what you want i.e. writing `console.log` after `con.query` in the same block and also you don't want `console.log` in seperate function (this is what I understand from the question and your comments in other answers)

To achieve this you'll have to wrap `con.query` in a promise and use `await` to wait till the promise resolves.

```
var button_settings=[];
await new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    con.query("SELECT * from ht_button", function (err, result, fields){
        if (err) reject(err)
        button_settings.push(result);
        resolve()
    });
}).catch(function(err){/* handle err */})
console.log(button_settings);
```

How the only problem is that you can only use `await` inside an `async` function. So let's wrap the whole in code an `async` function

Final code:

```
async function doStuff(){
    var button_settings=[];
    await new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        con.query("SELECT * from ht_button", function (err, result, fields){
            if (err) reject(err)
            button_settings.push(result);
            resolve()
        });
    }).catch(function(err){/* handle err */})
    console.log(button_settings);
}
doStuff();
```

I have not tested this code with actual mysql thing... But I here's a equivalent test :

```js
async function doStuff(){
  var button_settings=[];
  await new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    setTimeout(function(){
      button_settings = ["foobar"];
      resolve();
    },1000)
  });
  console.log(button_settings);
}
doStuff();
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but its not working let me check it again and get back to you. thanks for solution.

Comment: i have tried this code.

var array_name = [];

con.connect(function(err) {
 async function doStuff(){
  var button_settings=[];
  await new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
   con.query("SELECT * FROM vm_admin", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) reject(err)
     button_settings.push(result);
    resolve();
   });
  }).catch(function(err){/* handle err */})
  console.log(button_settings);
 }
 doStuff();
});

but its giving error : Unexpected token function

Comment: @VikasChauhan can you tell which function token is the error refering by seeing the line and column number... Also please share which nodejs version you are using...

Comment: async function doStuff(){
      ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3

Comment: async functions are not supported your nodejs version check this [table](https://node.green/#ES2017-features-async-functions) You'll have to update your nodejs verison

Comment: downloaded , node version v9.11.1 still same issue

Comment: @Vikas Chauhan what's the error now? same? Just recheck your version by "node --version" in your shell. Because I doubt it's updated

Comment: its updated i have checked and i found the issue i am updating answer ,
thanks all of you for support.
have a awesome day ahead ;)

Comment: @Vikas Chauhan Np, happy to help :)

Comment: @Vikas Chauhan dude you can't copy my code to write your own answer and then accept it... That's not how StackOverflow works... Imagine if I didn't post this answer would have you been able to write your own answer or solve your problem? My answer deserves to be accepted... I would love to hear your reply

Comment: you are right , its done by mistake so sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

You are querying the database which is asynchronous in nature thus the `console.log` does not wait for the result from `con.query` and executes immediately after that. Thus, you get `[]` printed. But if you have records in `result` after the query is completed then you will get the array printed in console if you put the `console.log(button_settings);` inside the `con.query` function like this:

**Change code to**

```
var button_settings=[];
con.query("SELECT * from ht_button", function (err, result, fields){
   if (err) throw err;
   button_settings.push(result);
   console.log(button_settings);  //console after the query completes
});
```

So, to make the flow work like a synchronous where you will use the value of `button_settings`, create a private function like this,

```
var button_settings=[];
con.query("SELECT * from ht_button", function (err, result, fields){
   if (err) throw err;
   button_settings.push(result);
   _processButtonSettings();
});

//put all your code related to button_settings here
function _processButtonSettings(){
  console.log(button_settings);
  //and more code...
}
```

Comment: i want the result out side of the query  block, i am using mysql

Comment: This is asynchronous call so what you can do is put all your code in a private function and call that from inside `con.query` callback so that it will get the value of `button_settings` at that time. @VikasChauhan.

Comment: i want value out side of function not in another function. i have tried the same thing in PHP its working fine but i don't know why its not working in node js

Comment: Then @VikasChauhan check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32850045/node-js-synchronous-queries-with-mysql#answer-32850828

Answer (score 0):

connection.query is async, which mean when your call your `console.log(button_settings)`, `button_settings` has not been set yet.

```
var button_settings=[];
con.query("SELECT * from ht_button", function (err, result, fields){
   if (err) throw err;
   else setValue(result);
});
function setValue(value) {
  button_settings = value;
  console.log(button_settings);
}
```

Comment: This will surely do not work, as I said the query to db is asynchronous so your code still fails.

Comment: Check now @VikasChauhan

Comment: i want value out side of function not in another function. i have tried the same thing in PHP its working fine but i don't know why its not working in node js

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement Promise [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html)

```
console.log
```

fired before the query function callback

Comment: Having such a reputation does not suites you for giving such an abstract answer

Answer (score 0):

```
   var res1=[];
   var res2=[];
   var res3=[];
   async function doStuff(){

    await new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        con.query("SELECT * FROM vm_admin", function (err, result, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            resolve();
            res1.push(result);
        });
    });     

    await new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        con.query("SELECT * FROM vm_banks", function (err, result, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            resolve();
            res2.push(result);
        });
    });     

    console.log(res1);  
    console.log('----------------');
    console.log(res2);  

}
doStuff();
```

I have checked above code and its working fine , thanks all of you for your quick support.